# Passing data from child component to parent component

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I am trying to pass alerts from my child components to parent component.

I have following app component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
```

App.component.html:

```
<header>
Some header
</header>
<clr-alert [clrAlertType]="'alert-warning'" [clrAlertAppLevel]="true">
    <div class="alert-item">
        <span class="alert-text">
            {{My_Alert_value_that_I want to pass from child}}
        </span>
        <div class="alert-actions">
            <button class="btn alert-action">Fix</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</clr-alert>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My Child component:

```
@Component({
    styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss'],
    templateUrl: './child.component.html',
})
export class ChildComponent {
  alerts: string
  constructor(){
    this.alerts = "";
  }

   this.alert = "My alerts, which I want to show on the app.component.html"
}
```

Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html gives good examples on how to do that. Especially https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent seems interesting for you

Comment: Have you searched on SO? There are many, many questions and answers here ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data From Child Component Into Parent Component AngularJS 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40992140/passing-data-from-child-component-into-parent-component-angularjs-2)

Comment: I have searched, I found many from parent to child, but could not find chile to parent comuunication.. I am going through the docs which @korgen suggested now

Comment: https://angular.io/search/#stq=%40output()&stp=1

Answer (score 0):

You can expose data from the child to the parent by using the `EventEmitter`, and handling the event in the parent component.

The official docs have a really good example of using `EventEmitter`:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html